# Do a currency conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Hi long time lurker first question. New to SQL and I am trying to do a currency conversion by following the code written by person no longer employed here.  I keep getting the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'." and I cant quite figure out why.  I'm basically converting price per gallon in USD $ to PPL in CND $  using our in house exchange table. Giving me a headache because I can usually find an answer somewhere.

SQL Server 2005

```
   CASE
          WHEN 
                CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),([Tractor Cost]-(([Tractor Cost]/([Tractor Cost]+[Reefer Cost])) * [Rebate Amount]) )/[Tractor Gallons]) is NULL THEN 0 
                ELSE  
                CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),([Tractor Cost]-(([Tractor Cost]/([Tractor Cost]+[Reefer Cost])) * [Rebate Amount]) )/[Tractor Gallons]) * 3.785 *

 CASE
          WHEN [Currency Type] = 'U' THEN

                (SELECT TOP 1 cex_rate  
                 FROM dbo.currency_exchange
                 WHERE [Transaction Date] >= [cex_date]
                 ORDER BY cex_date DESC   
                  )
            ELSE 0 
            END  AS 'Tractor Rebate Price',
```

Comment: You need an `END` to close the outer `CASE`.  If you indent your code properly that would be more evident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close both your `CASE` statements with `END`.

This is your problem, I think. You have 2 `CASE` usages but 1 `END` only.